# Check whether radio button is checked or not in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <input type="radio" name="a" />
 <input type="radio" name="a" />
 <input type="radio" name="b" />
 <input type="radio" name="b" />
```

I want to make sure that the `both group` of `radiobutton` must be checked, for this i tried :

```
if($("input[type=radio,name=a]:checked").length > 0 && 
   $("input[type=radio,name=b]:checked").length > 0)
{    
/* do something */
}
```

But not working , can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    if($("input[type=radio][name=a]:checked").length > 0 &&   
   $("input[type=radio][name=b]:checked").length > 0)  
{      
/* do something */  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** another approach: http://jsfiddle.net/Mwkjs/

**code**

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {

    if ($("input[name='a']").is(":checked") && $("input[name='b']").is(":checked")) { 
        /* do something */
        alert('do something');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it if you are using JQuery 1.9+

```
if ($("#selector").prop('checked')){
   //Code goes here
}
```

I know this is a old question, Answered in case if some one still looking for an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("input:radio[name=a]").is(':checked') && $("input:radio[name=b]").is(':checked')){

/* do something */

}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/mck6e/

Answer (score 0):

To select several attributes you should separate them: [type=radio][name=a]
Anyways for input elements, if you want,  you can omit the type attribute comparison, and even the word 'input' as there are specific selectors for each type (:radio, :checkbox, :submit, etc...), so in this case you can also apply:

```
if($('[name= a]:radio:checked').length>0 && $('[name= b]:radio:checked').length>0)
{
/*...*/
}
```